# Microsoft Graph Toolkit (MGT) - How do I modify/add request headers for the MGT-GET component?

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-toolkit

Trying to figure out how to modify request headers for the graph client toolkit and have it apply when using the GET component.  I don't necessarily want to override the entire graph client.

---

For reference, here's how you do it:

```
// Already likely on page, adding as reference
TeamsProvider.microsoftTeamsLib = microsoftTeams;
const provider = new TeamsProvider(config);
```

```
    const options = {
        authProvider: provider,
        fetchOptions: { headers: {'ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}}
    };     
    const client = Client.initWithMiddleware(options);
    provider.graph = new Graph(client)
```

```
// Now set provider with new graph
Providers.globalProvider = provider
```

Comment: hmm, interesting ask... check a related feature request filed @ [MGT repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/653).

Comment: I saw that before while searching around.  Was hoping the only option wasn't overriding the graph client.  As much as I want to love the GET component, 90% of the time I can't use it because of the filtering/query limitations of the graph.

Comment: yeah, i agree. Unfortunately that's the workaround i see at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten this to work without having to re-initialize the graph client by doing this:

```
Providers.globalProvider.graph.client.config.fetchOptions = { headers: {'ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}}
```

You can also remove the request headers by setting fetchOptions to `{}`. This can be toggled at any time between requests, and can be set even after the globalProvider has been initialized without having to re-create the middleware chain.

I posted a comment in the issues section of the MGT repo [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/653#issuecomment-1435757122).